# MySQLdb executemany not adding data

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to add data to a table (test_copy) using the MySQLdb executemany command, as follows:

```
db = mdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=3306,user='XXXX',db="test")
cursor = db.cursor()
COM = "insert into test_copy (Short_Model) VALUES (%s)"
VALS = ['213','3232','fd','sadad']
cursor.executemany(COM,VALS)
cursor.close
```

Note: Name of Table = test_copy, Column Name = Short_Model

Problem is that the command runs without any errors but when I check the table no data has been added.

Apologies if this is an easy problem but it's driving me crazy for the last few hours.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you @Jon Clements and @Abhishek Mishra - You have returned my sanity. Here is the final solution for those interested:

```
db = mdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=3306,user='xxxx',db="test")
cursor = db.cursor()
COM = "insert into test_copy (Short_Model) VALUES (%s)"
VALS = ['213','3232','fd','sadad']
cursor.executemany(COM,VALS)
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.close` should be `cursor.close()`, but you normally would want to `cursor.commit()` just to make sure your changes are reflected in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

A `commit()` call is needed to finalise things in db. The docs don't clarify if `executemany` automatically commits the changes. Also turning on auto commit, `cursor.autocommit(True)` could be helpful.

Comment: In my experience, `executemany` does automatcially commit, although I would prefer it did not.